# Parse and store using Apache Nutch

Tags: parsing, web-crawler, hbase, nutch

I am trying to develop a Crawler to crawl `youtube.com` and parse the meta information(title, description, publisher etc) and store these into Hbase/other storage systems. I understood that I have to write plugin(s) to achieve this. But I'm confused what plugins I need to write for this. I am inspecting with this four -

```
Parser
ParserFilter
Indexer
IndexFilter
```

To parse the specific metadata information for youtube page, do I need to write a custom Parser plugin or ParseFilter plugin along with using `parse-html` plugin?

After parsing, to store the entry in Hbase/other storage system do I require to write a IndexWriter plugin? By indexing, we generally understand indexing in Solr, ElasticSearch etc. But I don't need to index in any search engine obviously. So, how can I store them in some store say Hbase after parsing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since youtube is a web page, you'll need to write an `HtmlParseFilter` which gives you access to the raw HTML fetched from the server, but at the moment youtube a LOT of javascript and neither `parse-html` or `parse-tika` support executing the js code, so I'll advice you to use the protocol-selenium plugin so you'll delegate the rendering of a webpage to the selenium driver and get the HTML back (after all the JS has been executed). After you write your own `HtmlParseFilter` you'll need to write your own `IndexingFilter`, in this case you'll only need to specify what info you want to send to your backend, this is totally backend-agnostic and relies only on the Nutch codebase (that's why you'll need your own `IndexWriter`).

I assume that you're using Nutch 1.x, in this case yes you need to write a custom `IndexWriter` for your backend (which is fairly easy). If you use Nutch 2.x you'll have access to several backends through Apache Gora but then you'll have some features missing (like protocol-selenium).

Comment: As the question is pretty old now, I've already did what you've suggested here recently. Thanks for your detailed answer.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response :)

Comment: Hi @JorgeLuis can you please answer this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43993032/generate-only-unfetched-urls-instead-of-scored-nutch-2-3

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use something like **Crawler4j** for your purposes.

The real power of Nutch is utilized when you want to do a much wider search or you want to index your data directly into Solr/ES. But since you just want to download data for each URL, I would totally go with Crawler4j. It's much easier to setup and does not require complex configurations.