# Generate only unfetched urls instead of scored Nutch 2.3

Tags: apache, web-crawler, nutch

Is there any way to generate only the un-fetched urls instead of based on score in Nutch 2.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for Nutch 1.x you could use the jexl support that is shipped since Nutch 1.12 (I think):

```
$ bin/nutch generate -expr "status == db_unfetched"
```

with this command you're ensuring that only the URLs with a `db_unfetched` status are considered for generating the segments that you want to crawl.

This feature is still not available on 2.x branch, but writing a custom GeneratorJob could do the trick.

On the other hand, since the generator Job is already considering the score to sort the list of URLs to fetch, perhaps the easier way could be to write a custom [ScoringFilter](https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/2.x/src/java/org/apache/nutch/scoring/ScoringFilter.java).

For instance, if you take a look at: https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/2.x/src/java/org/apache/nutch/scoring/ScoringFilter.java#L69-L81 the ScoringFilter already provides a `generatorSortValue` method only for generating a scoring value for the generator job, so you could write your own to boost those URLs with an unfetched status.

Comment: Thanks! I think its also possible by removing all scoring-filters from 'plugin.includes' ?

Comment: Yep but in that case I think that you'll have all the urls with a 1.0 score without any distinction between the status so first comes first served/fetched in this case although perhaps the generator gather first the unfetched ones (according to the documentation) so could work. Not sure if in 2.x is the same.